# Choose the correct item based on luck Lua

Tags: list, lua, lua-table

Lets say I have this table.

```
Config.LootboxesRewards = {
    [1] = {
        {name = 'a45amg',               label = 'Mercedes A45 AMG ',    amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 3},
        {name = '720s',                 label = '720s mclaren',         amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 20},
        {name = 'bac2',                 label = 'bac2',                 amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 20},
        {name = 'm6prior',              label = 'BMW M6',               amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 19},
        {name = 'huracan',              label = 'Lamborghini Huracan',  amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 19},
        {name = 'yzfr6',                label = 'Yamaha R6',            amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 19},
    },
}
```

Based on that I would like to give the the player 1 item based on luck value on that table.
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "based on luck value"? Does higher luck mean = lesser chance? How much lesser? And how does the players luck come into play?

Comment: If you scroll on the right of that table that I posted you can see that there is one element called luck

Comment: Yes but what does that mean? Does a higher luck value indicate a rarer car, a less rare car? Easiest solution is to find the highest common divider, divide the luck values by that and add each entry as many times to a temporary table as the calculation results in. For example, if you have luck=5 and luck=20 the highest common divider is 5. Add the first item once (5/5=1) to a temporary table and the other one 4 times (20/5=4). Now choose a random index from that table

Comment: less luck idicates if the cas is really good for example Mercedes A45 AMG its a unique and rare car thats why we have 3 there. Thanks your answear really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to index `Config.LootboxesRewards[1]` with `math.random(#Config.LootboxesRewards[1])`

This assumes that you just want to give your player a random item with uniform distribution. If you want to vary the chanc of getting particular items I suggest you start here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability

Read:

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-math.random

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-math.randomseed

Comment: I use the math random but my problem is that I might have more values with the same luck and in the end I only have to return 1 of all these.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "more values with the same luck". if you have only one item to give away remove that item from the list befor you pick the next thing. luck is not a mathematical thing. please learn the proper terminology.

Comment: will you get a car every time? what's the probability of getting a super car? if you get one, what's the probability to get a specific super car? you cannot possibly model this if you don't understand the maths behind this.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to put the values with a higher chance (higher luck value) more often in the loot-table than the items with a lower change (lower luck value).

You can still keep your table for convenience and pre-process the table like this:

```lua
local function gcd(a, b)
    while a ~= b do
        if a > b then
            a = a - b
        else
            b = b - a
        end
    end

    return a
end

local function gcd_tbl(values, value_getter)
    if #values < 1 then
        return nil
    end

    value_getter = value_getter or function(v) return v end

    local result = value_getter(values[1])

    for i = 2, #values do
        result = gcd(result, value_getter(values[i]))
    end

    return result
end

local function process_rewards(tbl)
    local result = {}

    for id, rewards in pairs(tbl) do
        result[id] = {}

        local greatest_common_divisor = gcd_tbl(rewards, function(v) return v.luck end)

        for _, reward in ipairs(rewards) do
            for i = 1, reward.luck / greatest_common_divisor do
                table.insert(result[id], reward)
            end
        end
    end

    return result
end

Config.LootboxesRewards = process_rewards({
    [1] = {
        {name = 'a45amg',               label = 'Mercedes A45 AMG ',    amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 3},
        {name = '720s',                 label = '720s mclaren',         amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 20},
        {name = 'bac2',                 label = 'bac2',                 amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 20},
        {name = 'm6prior',              label = 'BMW M6',               amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 19},
        {name = 'huracan',              label = 'Lamborghini Huracan',  amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 19},
        {name = 'yzfr6',                label = 'Yamaha R6',            amount = 1,     type = 'car',   luck = 19},
    }
})
```

You can then choose a random index from the table to find the reward:

```lua
function get_random_reward(lootbox_id)
    local lootbox_rewards = Config.LootboxesRewards[lootbox_id]
    if not lootbox_rewards then
        return nil
    end

    return lootbox_rewards[math.random(#lootbox_rewards)]
end

get_random_reward(1)
```

EDIT:
If you wish to indicate the other way around (higher luck = less chance to drop), you could chance these 2 functions:

```lua
local function gcd_and_max_tbl(values, value_getter)
    if #values < 1 then
        return nil, nil
    end

    value_getter = value_getter or function(v) return v end

    local value = value_getter(values[1])
    local gcd_result, max_result = value, value

    for i = 2, #values do
        value = value_getter(values[i])
        gcd_result = gcd(gcd_result, value)
        max_result = math.max(max_result, value)
    end

    return gcd_result, max_result
end

local function process_rewards(tbl)
    local result = {}

    for id, rewards in pairs(tbl) do
        result[id] = {}

        local greatest_common_divisor, max_luck = gcd_and_max_tbl(rewards, function(v) return v.luck end)
        local max_relevant_luck = max_luck / greatest_common_divisor

        for _, reward in ipairs(rewards) do
            for i = 1, max_relevant_luck - (reward.luck / greatest_common_divisor) + 1 do
                table.insert(result[id], reward)
            end
        end
    end

    return result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if luck simply is how likely it is to be picked, so that a car with luck 10 has double chance to be picked than one with 5 you could do it like this

```
function pickBasedOnLuck(list)
    local totalLuck = 0
    for i, car in ipairs(list) do
        totalLuck = totalLuck + car.luck
    end
    local pick = math.random(totalLuck)
    for i, car in ipairs(list) do
        if pick > car.luck then
            pick = pick - car.luck
        else
            return car
        end
    end
end
```

so in your case it could be called like `pickBasedOnLuck(Config.LootboxesRewards[1])`.